# Flutter - How to add a row in Excel Online

Tags: flutter, dart, excel-online

I am trying to develop an application which will work with an Excel sheet stored in OneDrive (Excel Online). I want to use flutter to add data into the excel sheet however I cannot find any APIs to do so. So far I only found the flutter excel package, however as per my understanding it is only used for local files.

I can download the file, update it and then reupload the file however, I would prefer everything to happen online. Is it possible to do so? I know flutter has a Google Sheets API is a similar thing available for Excel Online?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create GCP project to access Google Cloud APIs. For creating a google cloud project, see https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/get-started.
2. You need to enable Google Sheet API.
3. You need to create required credentials in the created project.
   https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials

   ```
     i. API key  - For public sheets.
    ii. OAuth Credentials - For private sheets.
   iii. Service Account Credentials - For private sheets.
   ```
4. Refer here for the Google sheet API for writing to a particular sheet. There you can have `curl` requests for each operations.
   https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing
5. Finally, you can use the `curl` request in flutter as mentioned here.
   https://pub.dev/documentation/curl/latest/

Comment: Hello Nishothan! Thank you for your answer, but I am really looking for a way to edit Microsoft Excel Online spreadsheet. I know it is possible to do so in Google Sheets, but my app needs to work with Microsoft Excel Online data. Is there a way to edit Microsoft Excel Online sheets using flutter?